# How can i implement pagination in Asp.net MVC through nopCommerce?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, nopcommerce

How can i implement pagination in Asp.net MVC through nopCommere ? I want to Implement pagination in nopCommerce site ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IPagedList.  Refer to Nop.Services.Catalog.ProductService IPagedList SearchProducts();